# AWS SDK, C#: Catch GetUserAsync Exception and Continue

Tags: c#, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I'm on dotnetcore 3.1(C#) and I'm using the AWS SDK.  I have a function to test credentials, which I test with the `GetUserAsync` method on the `AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient`.  The problem is that when I have bad credentials, an exception is thrown and execution is stopped.

```
public async Task<GetUserResponse> TestCredentials(string accessId, string accessKey)
{
    AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessId, accessKey);
    AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient client = new AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient(awsCredentials);
    var userAsync = client.GetUserAsync();

    try
    {
         await userAsync;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the error here
        var something = 100;
    }

    return userAsync.Result;
}
```

When an incorrect login is used, there is still a result that I would like to process, but as execution has stopped (at least in my test), I can't do anything with it.  How do I tell my code to catch the exception, and still return the `userAsync.Result`?

Below is my test for completeness.

```
[TestMethod()]
public async Task TestBadCredentialsTest()
{
    var awsAccessKeyId = "WRONG";
    var awsSecretAccessKey = "EVENWORSE";

    AWSCredentialsService awsCredentialsService = new AWSCredentialsService();
    var getUserResponse = await awsCredentialsService.TestCredentials(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey);


    // Test never gets to here
    var httpStatus = getUserResponse.HttpStatusCode;
    Assert.AreNotEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, httpStatus);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A task may complete with an exception *or* a result. It can never have both.

Different HTTP client libraries have different capabilities - and I'm not familiar with AWS - but many of them have a kind of "detailed exception" type that can be thrown. If you catch that specific exception type, then you can get exception details, and sometimes the entire HTTP response itself. However, the types and methods you have available for this are all up to the client library.